# Java Regex: can't assign variable to pattern.compile()

Tags: java, regex

Here is my code, I have looked at the library which states it can accept a String. Not sure what the issue is here.

```
String currentText = "";
String regex = "";

public void prepRegex() {
        currentText = textField.getText();
        regex = regexField.getText();
}

public void checkFunc() {
    prepRegex();

    try {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regex); // This doesn't work <---
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(currentText);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
                // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
                // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
            }
        } 
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex syntax is quite specific, not any string, your string must not conform... could you update your question with the string causing the error....

Comment: @AndyTurner Of course! Thank you, make it an answer if you want me to check it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the variable in its own initializer:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regex);
        ^ This                  ^ is the same symbol as this
```

If you want to refer to  the instance variable (above, `String regex = "";`), qualify it with `this`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(this.regex);
```